# Can married couples climb hills in first six months after marriage?

Tags: scripture, rituals

Is there any restriction in Hinduism that newly married couples should not climb hills for the first six months after their marriage?

Comment: What makes you think they cannot do that?

Comment: This belief is there in Telugu states and some people says it as a  reason for Srinivasa and Padmavathi to not climb hill for six months after their marriage @Wikash_